# MacBook (2015) disable boot sound

Tags: boot, mac, audio

Before saying that this is a duplicate (or triplicate) I want to let you know that I have tried all the following suggestions:

First I tried these terminal suggestions:

> [How to Disable the Boot Sound (or “Startup Chime”) on a Mac](https://www.howtogeek.com/260693/how-to-disable-the-boot-sound-or-startup-chime-on-a-mac)

Then this with the login scripts

> https://jacksadvice.com/turn-off-the-mac-startup-sound/1515/

And a different version 'set volume **with** output muted'

> [How To Turn Off The Mac Startup Sound](https://superuser.com/questions/200393/how-to-disable-startup-sound-on-a-mac)

None of them works!

The only thing that works for me is to mute the sound before shutting down. Now I **ALWAYS** forget that, so I would not mind a solution that mutes my mac every time I shut it down - and then I'll have to disable mute after boot every time (that I would not mind).

## Bonus info

- macOS Mojave
- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)

Comment: There are a slew of alternatives at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168092/disable-os-x-startup-sound - Onyx works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Tetsujin I found this solution https://github.com/matteoacrossi/nobootsound - which works for me, finally.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a headphone port, plug in some headphones.  They don't even need to be actual headphones - just the plug with the cable cut off from a broken cable will do fine.  When anything is plugged into the headphone port, then Mac will attempt to push the audio boot noise through that instead of the standard speakers.